# Does not start Python Django ver 3.7.1 django ver 3.0.4

Tags: python-3.7

$ py manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 17 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

March 15, 2020 - 14:51:19
Django version 3.0.4, using settings 'myfirst.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Suslicke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Suslicke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Suslicke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Suslicke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 139, in inner_run
    ipv6=self.use_ipv6, threading=threading, server_cls=self.server_cls)
  File "C:\Users\Suslicke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 206, in run
    httpd = httpd_cls(server_address, WSGIRequestHandler, ipv6=ipv6)
  File "C:\Users\Suslicke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 67, in **init**
    super().**init**(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Suslicke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socketserver.py", line 449, in **init**
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Users\Suslicke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Users\Suslicke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\server.py", line 139, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
  File "C:\Users\Suslicke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 676, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 9: invalid continuation byte

Comment: What is the hostname of your machine?

Comment: Sorry, just trying to understand. Where is it?

Comment: Host machine, my pc... It is local host

Comment: In a cmd window, please type the command `hostname` it will give you the hostname of your machine. If it contains "weird" characters it may be the cause of your error.

Comment: thanks a lot. Realy!

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem ?